# if i use re.findall How to register in order not to separate the point

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I need to extract the numbers from this string :

```
str="((8,52),(30,52),2,0.5)"
```

if i used : `re.findall('\d+',str)`
i well get :

```
['20', '48', '48', '48', '2', '0', '5']
```

There is a problem with `0.5`

How do I get 0.5 together to get :

```
['20', '48', '48', '48', '2', '0.5']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`re.findall("\d+\.\d+|\d+",str)`

The first grouping in the regular expression will find numbers on either side of a decimal, and the second grouping will find whole numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Use a numeric parse standard `(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)`
Covers all cases:

> 5
>   5.
>   5.1
>   .1

Answer (score 1):

```
re.findall(r'\d+\.?\d*',str)
```

output:

```
['8', '52', '30', '52', '2', '0.5']
```